# WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session Error forwarding the request Connect to my_ip:5555 [/my_ip] failed: Connection timed out

Tags: selenium, networking, selenium-webdriver, amazon-ec2, selenium-grid

I installed selenium node on AWS windows and started it. And I setup Jenkins, git, Seleniuim hub on AWS Linux. When i'm building app on Jenkins, selenium hub is trying to connect to selenium node of AWS windows with *private IP address*. And i'm getting following exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
Error forwarding the new session Error forwarding the request Connect to windows_private_ip:5555 [/windows_private_ip] failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
Command duration or timeout: 190.25 seconds
Build info: version: '3.5.1', revision: '9c21bb67ef', time: '2017-08-17T15:26:08.955Z'
System info: host: 'some_host_name', ip: 'some_ip', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.76-3.78.amzn1.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
Caused by: org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: Error forwarding the new session Error forwarding the request Connect to windows_private_ip:5555 [/windows_private_ip] failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
```

Grid Node command:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./drivers/windows-driver/chromedriver.exe -jar C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -role node -hub http://ip_address:4444/grid/register
```

My code is:

```
if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("FF")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "drivers/windows-driver/geckodriver.exe");
            DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            // Set the platform where we want to run our test- we can use
            // MAC and Linux and other platforms as well
            cap.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
            cap.setCapability("gecko", true);
            // Here you can use hub address, hub will take the
            // responsibility to execute the test on respective node
            URL url = new URL("http://hub_public_ip:4444/wd/hub");
            // Create driver with hub address and capability
            gbb = PageFactory.initElements(new RemoteWebDriver(url, cap), GuruBase.class);
        } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("IE")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "drivers/windows-driver/IEDriverServer.exe");
            gbb = PageFactory.initElements(new InternetExplorerDriver(), GuruBase.class);

        } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("GC")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "drivers/windows-driver/chromedriver.exe");
            ChromeOptions cho = new ChromeOptions();
            cho.addArguments("disabled-extensions");
            cho.addArguments("--start-maximized");
            gbb = PageFactory.initElements(new ChromeDriver(cho), GuruBase.class);
        }

        else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("html")) {
            gbb = PageFactory.initElements(new HtmlUnitDriver(true), GuruBase.class);
        }
```

I'm running selenium hub on Jenkins.

Comment: Update the question with your code trials, grid hub command, grid node command and error stack trace for further analysis.

Comment: @DebanjanB, I updated my question. Please give me solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution will be to change :

```
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=./drivers/windows-driver/chromedriver.exe -jar C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -role node -hub http://ip_address:4444/grid/register
```

As you are using **Dwebdriver.gecko.driver** with **chromedriver.exe**

To either :

- Use *GeckoDriver* :

  ```
  java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=./drivers/windows-driver/geckodriver.exe -jar C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -role node -hub http://ip_address:4444/grid/register
  ```
- Use *Chromedriver* :

  ```
  java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./drivers/windows-driver/chromedriver.exe -jar C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -role node -hub http://ip_address:4444/grid/register
  ```

Additionally, you need to check your `if()` loop as you have a mixed up representation of *Windows* and *Linux* styles in `System.setProperty()` line as follows :

- *GeckoDriver* :

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "drivers/windows-driver/geckodriver.exe");
  ```
- *ChromeDriver* :

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "drivers/windows-driver/chromedriver");
  ```
- *IEDriverServer* :

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "drivers/windows-driver/IEDriverServer.exe");
  ```

> **Note** : On *Windows Systems* you need to mention the extension **.exe** part e.g. **geckodriver.exe** while on *Linux Systems* you need strip off the extension **.exe** part e.g. **chromedriver**

Comment: @DebenjanB, I changed gecko with chrome. But still getting same exception.

Comment: @DebenjanB, I did all changes you suggested but getting same issue.

Comment: See you are still messing up the _Linux System_ based commands. Grid Node Command still includes `chromedriver.exe` as well as your code block includes `geckodriver.exe`and `IEDriverServer.exe`. Read my answe carefully.

Comment: @DebenjanB, I'm firing Grid node command on AWS windows. I want to execute script on chrome browser on windows system. And I started Grid hub on Jenkins on AWS linux. And i'm getting **INFO: Marking the node http:// aws_windows_private-IP:5555 as down: cannot reach the node for 2 tries
Feb 27, 2018 9:51:28 AM org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy onEvent**

Comment: I think you are confusing on how Grid Hub & Node connects. **selenium hub is trying to connect to selenium node of AWS windows** is incorrect. Rather _Grid Hub_ **forwards the request**. Update the question with all your _Framework Configuration_, _Code Block_ , _Grid Hub Command_, _Grid Node Command_ and complete _Error Stack Trace_ for further analysis.

Comment: @DebenjanB, I'm getting above error with FireFox browser with firefox grid node command. When i'm firing grid command for chrome getting 
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/My_Login_Windows_FireFox/drivers/windows-driver/chromedriver.exe**

Comment: Of-coarse you are seeing the correct **java.lang.IllegalStateException** as you are trying with **FireFox browser with firefox grid node command** through **`chromedriver.exe`**

Answer (score 1):

This probably caused by your ip not matched. I met the same error and I found that there are two IPv4 address for my machine. One is Eather net and another is WLAN.
 Steps:

- Disconnect the Wi-Fi.
- Use command : `ipconfig` to check my IPv4 address (there's only one IP there).
- With one IP only it should create session correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are using your office computer to make transaction between your node and your hub.

to some extent, you can push your code from office computer <=> github <=> AWS EC2 console.
but registering it as a node / hub and trying to execute the test case may not be possible.

please try with a server in same environment.